# Running Python code by calling it with VBA code

Tags: python, vba, shell, path, export-to-csv

I cannot get this Python code to run by calling it with a VBA macro.

The Python code which writes a CSV to my desktop.

```py
import pandas as pd
string=['hello world','Sup']
DFstring=pd.DataFrame(string)
DFstring.to_csv("C:/Users/Peter_K/Desktop/test.csv")
```

I attempt to call this code with VBA code in Excel.

```vb
Sub xls2py()
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String
    ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path

    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    PythonExe = """C:\Users\Peter_K\anaconda3\python.exe"""
    PythonScript = "C:\Users\Peter_K\Desktop\Untitled3.py"

    objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript
    Set objShell = Nothing

End Sub
```

A black box command prompt box flashes on the screen but the CSV does not write.

Comment: I suspect the issue lies within the python script.  I used your VBA code to run a much simpler script that wrote text to a file and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was two fold. First I was not importing numpy in my python script. Second I did not have my path set up correctly. A great and up to date video on how to do this is linked below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOwCiZKj2rg&t=510s